# Inherit data of Parent Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

Can we inherit Send Classification from Parent Business Unit into Child Business Unit in marketing cloud?

Answer (score 0):

No, You need to create send classification in each child BU.
You can use [ssjs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_sendClassificationFunctions.htm) to do this automatically.

Comment: Thank you.
Is there any document or link related to send classifications inheritance among business unit.